# i need help to prove this problem(functional analysis)

Tags: functional-analysis

show that the annihilator of a set M in an inner product space X is a closed subspace of X.
[image]

Comment: What do you think needs to be shown to prove that $M^\perp$ is closed?

Comment: we must show that the clouser of M⊥ equal M

Comment: @quba, start with a sequence in $M^\perp$.

Comment: @ Hagen von Eitzen, we must show that the clouser of M⊥ equal M

Comment: @quba, can you write out what $M^\perp$ is first?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to do it that doesn't explicitly use sequences:

Let the base field be $\Bbb F$, where $\Bbb F = \Bbb R \; \text{or} \; \Bbb C$.

Start with the definition of $M^\bot$:

$M^\bot = \{ x \in X \mid \langle m, x \rangle = 0, \forall m \in M \}; \tag{1}$

next, note that for any $m \in M$, the map

$\phi_m:X \to \Bbb F, \; \phi_m(x) = \langle m, x \rangle \tag{2}$

is a continuous linear functional from $X$ to $\Bbb F$; indeed, it is bounded since, by Cauchy-Schwarz, $\vert \phi_m(x) \vert = \vert \langle m, x \rangle \vert \le \Vert m \Vert \Vert x \Vert$; linearity follows directly from the axiomatic properties of the inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ on $X$.  Since $\phi_m$ is continuous, $\ker \phi_m$ is a closed subspace of $X$.  Now it is easy to see that

$M^\bot = \bigcap_{m \in M} \ker \phi_m; \tag{3}$

indeed, (3) may be seen as a re-statement of the defintion (1); finish off with the fact that the intersection of a any set of closed subspaces is again a closed subspace.  ***QED.***

***Nota Bene:***  I think it is worth pointing out that *closed* here means the general topological notion of closure:  a set $Y$ is closed if and only if its complement is open.  Sequential closure can't be invoked here since don't know that $X$ is Cauchy complete, i.e. that Cauchy sequences actually have limit points, *in $X$*.  ***End of Note.***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: I like the proof and upvoted, but fail to see the relevance of the note, as the usual definition of closure in a metric space does not refer to Cauchy sequences or completeness: If $E$ is a subset of a metric space we say that $x\in \overline{E}$ iff $x$ is the limit of a convergent sequence with terms in $E$. In fact this definition is equivalent to the topological definition of closure for any metric space. In more general topological space this holds as a theorem with "the" before "limit" replaced by "a" and "sequence" replaced by "net".

Comment: Also, the notion of a Cauchy sequence does not exist in a general topological space and therefore it would be strange if the closure in a metric space (which should be equivalent to the topological definition) used the notion of Cauchy sequences in its definition.

Comment: This problem was take from Kreyzig's Functional Analysis. $X$ is is taken to be a normed space.

Comment: @Wavelet:  Sorry it took so long to get back to you.  Of course, the note is not, *strictly speaking*, essential to the argument I presented.  But if you will recall there was a now-apparently-deleted discussion in the comment thread in which an argument based upon sequences was proposed; I can't recall all the details at present, but as I was writing up my proof it gave me pause . . . ***to be continued . . .***

Comment: @1950RobertLewis That is no problem at all. That comment above was mine and I deleted it because I thought it would be more useful for the OP to try and figure it out himself. My proof went as follows, and did not use the notion of completeness or Cauchy sequences: Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbf N}$ be a convergent sequence in $X$ with terms in $M^\perp$. Let $y\in M$. Then $\forall n\in\mathbf N, \langle x_n,y\rangle=0$, so $\lim_{n\to\infty}\langle x_n,y\rangle=0$. The inner product is continuous so $\langle \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n,y\rangle=0$. We conclude that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n\in M^\perp$.

Comment: From this it follows (with the characterization of closedness in metric spaces) that $M^\perp$ is closed. It might be helpful to note for the OP that this does not yet show that $M^\perp$ is a closed linear subspace because we have not shown that it is indeed a subspace (which is of course very easy with the sesquilinearity of the inner product).